# Headless webview

Tags: ios, nativescript, wkwebview, nativescript-vue

Is there a way to create a headless WebView instance in Nativescript (Vue) for use with [nativescript-webview-interface](https://github.com/shripalsoni04/nativescript-webview-interface) (which expects a Nativescript view)? How can I instantiate the Vue component so it creates the native webview in the background (similar to `document.createElement` on web)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the core way of creating elements

```
import { WebView } from "tns-core-modules/ui/web-view";

...
methods: {
   createWebView: function() {
      const webView = new WebView();
      // Remember to pass in context in case of android
      wv._setupAsRootView({});
      wv.onLoaded();
      ...
   }
}
...
```

Comment: This doesn't properly initialize the web view (the underlying `WKWebView` isn't created). Thus trying to use it in nativescript-webview-interface crashes with `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.webView.ios.constructor')` because the `ios` property doesn't exist yet. [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=vpKFNm)

Comment: I have updated your [playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=vpKFNm&v=2).

Comment: I also had to add `wv.onLoaded()` to get it to initialize properly. [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=vpKFNm&v=6) demoing working WVI.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thanks for noticing and sharing I have updated the snippet.